# Java sync Files between FTP and Client

Tags: java, file, ftp, synchronization

i need a method for sync Files between FTP server and client on click.

i search for days but all i could find is too difficult for my low java skills.

does anyone know some easy way to do that?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

You can use FTPClient from apache commons library (FTPClient encapsulates all the functionality necessary to store and retrieve files from an FTP server). If this is too difficult for you, then you maybe need to read more Java articles and learn programming/language better.

Good example for FTPClient is already in JavaDoc: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html